# InternationalMountains app built on Xcode 5.1.1 (iOS SDK 7) not running on iOS - 8 simulator

Tags: xcode, ios8

I had the InternationalMountains app downloaded sometime back from apple website, I ran this app in iOS 7 simulator which actually worked. I tried running this app in iOS - 8 simulator that came with Xcode 6.0.1, which actually failed. The application crashes when I click on the app icon. I found this log from the Console app.

Dyld Error Message:
  program was built for Mac OS X and cannot be run in simulator.

So I had the source code of the InternationalMountains app and I opened the .xcodeproj file in Xcode 5.1.1 and built the application for iOS SDK 7 as the target to get the .app file, I even used this app in iOS - 8 simulator which agained failed to start with the same error as mentioned above. Saying it still built for Mac OS X.

But if I open the .xcodeproj file in Xcode 6.0.1 and build it against iOS 8 SDK and deploy the new app file in IOS - 8 simulator, then the app seems to work fine.

Is there something I am missing. I am very new to iOS development. Will the apps built in Xcode 5.1.1 for IOS SDK 7 run on IOS - 8 simulator.

Thanks in advance.